# alert problem on ticker.renko that triggers different from what i want

Tags: pine-script

I wrote a code that gets renko candles open close and plot it.then we have a condition that when two same color candle happened after a different color candle we put a triangle on indicator. Till here everything is ok. But when i create an alert with this condition alert trigers different with my condition. So can you tell me whats the problem?

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © zvkhtfg1x0

//@version=5
indicator("Renko candles", overlay=false)
renko_tickerid = ticker.renko(syminfo.tickerid , "ATR", 14)

[renko_open, renko_high, renko_low, renko_close] = request.security(renko_tickerid, timeframe.period, [open, high, low, close])
plotcandle(renko_open, renko_high, renko_low, renko_close, color = renko_close > renko_open ? color.green : color.red)



buy = renko_close > renko_open and renko_close[1] > renko_open[1] and renko_close[2] < renko_open[2]
    



sell = renko_close < renko_open and renko_close[1] < renko_open[1] and renko_close[2] > renko_open[2]




plotshape(buy ? bar_index : na , 'buy' , style = shape.triangleup , location = location.belowbar , color = color.green , size = size.small)

plotshape(sell ? bar_index : na , 'sell' , style = shape.triangledown , location = location.abovebar , color = color.red , size = size.small)

if buy
    alert('buy signal' , freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

if sell
    alert('sell signal' , freq = alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```